# Non-debug run in separate window or fullscreen

Tags: visual-studio-code

Obviously one would use vsCode mostly for debug runs. But it would be nice to code in Zen mode or fullscreen, then press ctrl + f5 and see the (voluminous) result in fullscreen. What might work the best is to have an option where the debug etc panes are not at the bottom of the editor, but in separate windows by themselves. Is there an option or hack to achieve this?

Edit: The best seems to be: Go Zen, on the debug pane click on the up arrow to "maximize panel size", and then toggle its visibility with ctrl + j. But I'm even greedier than that so I'm asking for more!

Comment: "Is there an option or hack to achieve this?" - VS Code doesn't have this feature at this time.

Comment: Thanks! Each person has their own preferences I guess. I'm very impressed with VS Code.